# round function returns wrong double estimation

Tags: c++, double, precision

I am trying to round the double up to 3 decimal points but ...

```
double round_double(double d){
    return round(d * 1000) / 1000;
}

int main() {
    double r = round_double(1.5 * 1.001);
    cout << r << endl;
    return 0; }
```

When I run it the result is 1.501... Why doesn't it return 1.502? Also when I change the round_double function to look like this:

```
return floor(d * 1000 + 0.5) / 1000;
```

It still produces 1.501... Any ideas why?

Comment: they call this math....

Comment: You are relying on the *exact* value of a double to be 100% precisely dead on. This is never a good idea. If that multiplication is off by any amount greater than zero, no matter how small, you will get the wrong result. So you are relying on a particular decimal amount have an *exact* representation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `1.5 * 1.001` doesn't have exact representation in `double`. It is treated as `1.5014999999999998`.

A very common way to fix this problem is to add (subtract) some epsilon value.

Your rounding function with epsilon correction might look like

```
double round_double(double d)
{
    const double epsilon = 10e-8;
    d = signbit(d) ? d - epsilon : d + epsilon;
    return round(d * 1000) / 1000;
}
```

Comment: what should that epsilon value be? I guess any value would lead to unexpected roundings in the opposite direction

Comment: @tobi303 If you're expecting exact results from `double` operations, you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz How did you conclude that I am expecting exact results from double operations?? I was just wondering how Stas wants to make the rounding exact by using an epislon. However, in the meantime he updated the answer and made it more clear.

Comment: @tobi303 You are concerned about unexpected roundings in the opposite direction.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes, because it doesnt help to fix rounding in one direction, at the cost of false rounding in the other direction. As I understood, this `round_double` function fixes not just rounding in one direction but both. It was just my ignorance/misunderstanding what he meant with "use an epsilon" (but not ignorance of inaccuracy of double operations). Sorry, I dont get your point but nevermind, dont worry, I wont have a bad time, because I am aware of rounding errors and imperfect representation of numbers ;)

Comment: @tobi303 The point is that you have three choices -- 1) Tolerate occasionally rounding up when you should not. 2) Tolerate occasionally rounding down when you should not. 3) Rely on perfect representation. -- The original code has 2. The suggestion is to have 1. If you don't like it, that leaves only 3. :)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz you might address this argument to Stas, because (imho) his answer suggests that his solution does a **correct** rounding (and even if it didnt look like, the orginial intention of my comment was to put this into question)

Comment: @tobi303 I've updated the answer to show that it is need to subtract epsilon in case of negative numbers. Does it address the issue?

Comment: my problem of understanding is not about negative numbers, but about e.g. `round_double(1.0005 - eps/2)`. Maybe I am missing something, but doesnt your function wrongly round up in this case?

Comment: @tobi303 An epsilon lets you determine if two floating point numbers are close enough to each other. So, if `abs(a-b) < eps` then `a` and `b` numbers should be treated as equal.

In case of your example, `1.5 - eps/2` is treated equal to `1.5`, according to our comparison/rounding rules, so yes, it should be rounded up.

Again, it is just one example of how to deal with floating point numbers. There are tons of methods to compare and round them.

Comment: @Stas Let me put it more clearly: Your method is not doing **correct** rounding. It does not fix the fundamental problem of unprecise representation of numbers. It is only correct up to some epsilon difference. Thus, please dont call it "correct". Sorry if I may sound rude, but honestly I am a little bit annoyed after this long discussion when my first comment was just saying "no this isnt correct rounding" obviously phrased in a way that it lead to some misunderstandings (obviously my fault).

Comment: @tobi303 ok, I see. Removed `correct` word from the answer)

Comment: @tobi303 As Slas explained, it is perfectly correct to treat two numbers withing epsilon as equal -- that is the purpose of epsilon. So that rounding is correct. You really only have the three choices I listed. I don't think it makes sense to argue that none of them are correct.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Let me try once more to make my point: The title says "round function returns wrong double estimation". When I read this, I assume that he was expecting rounding to work correctly. What i mean with "correct" is what you can do with numbers on a sheet of paper and I strongly believe that this was what the OP was expecting in the first place. When an answer states that there is a solution, that does correct rounding, the OP might think this method solves the problem and does "correct rounding". If it would not make sense to mention this, there was no question to begin with.